# How to reverse a stack in java using another stack?

Tags: java

I want to reverse a stack in java of the form `java.util.Stack` by using another stack. I know i can just push the top most element of `stack 1` to `stack 2` and `stack 2` will have reversed elements of `stack 1`. But the question requires me to reflect the answer in `stack 1` itself and not `stack 2`. Also i cannot use any more stacks. How to reverse and reflect the reversed answer in `stack 1` itself ?

Comment: Are you able or allowed to use another data structure as a temporary storage option? Maybe a `List` or an array?

Comment: Can you use a `Deque` as a stack?

Comment: Well this is possible with two stacks definitely. But only one stack case is interesting.

Comment: A) by doing your homework yourself (that is how you learn programming) B) by putting your question into a search engine. You know, for the people that are really not interested in learning programming themselves, using a search engine is actually an efficient strategy.

Comment: `java.util.Stack` implements the `List` interface, so just look for how to reverse a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack s1 = new Stack();
Stack s2 = new Stack();

s1.add(1);
s1.add(2);
s1.add(3);
s1.add(4);

s2.add(s1.pop());
s2.add(s1.pop());
s2.add(s1.pop());
s2.add(s1.pop());

s1 = s2;

System.out.println(s1);
```

You didn't say that you are not allowed to reassign the stack variable. This way you have the reversed order on `s1`.

Another way would be to use `Collections.reverse(s1);` which has basically the same effect

Comment: If you downvote also leave a comment as to why the downvote

Comment: I didnt downvote, but I find: this is a low quality "homework dump assignment" question. Some people think that such questions dont deserve answers.

Comment: I agree that homework questions don't deserve an answer in most (kinda all) cases if it is 100% that it is a homework question. This one doesn't seem to be 100% homework on first glance (no copied assignment etc. could have been a serious question)

Comment: OP says "But the question requires... " so it's 99% certain we have a homework assignment here.